# Simple linear regression code leads to unreasonable cost function

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to write a simple linear regression code from scratch as my first Machine Learning exercise. However, when I try to perform the gradient descent over a for loop, my code leads to unreasonable results (crazy high cost function and coefficients). This is clearly wrong since the cost function has to decrease over the steps. Can someone point where in my code I am doing wrong?  Here is a code example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,11,1)# simple feature values

y0 = 2 + 4*x # some true values for the coefficients

y_rand = np.random.uniform(low=-3,high=3,size = len(x)) # adding some randomness in the data

y = y0+y_rand

def linear_regression(x, y,a0,a1, learning_rate,iterate):

    m = len(x) # length of inputs
    for i in range(iterate):
        temp0 = a0
        temp1 = a1
        y_theory = temp0 + temp1*x
        J.append(np.sum( (y_theory-y)**2 )/2/m  ) # cost function
        da0 =learning_rate*np.sum(y_theory-y)/m
        da1 =learning_rate*np.sum((y_theory-y)*x)/m
        a0 = temp0-da0 #updating the intercept
        a1 = temp1 -da1#updating the slope
        pdb.set_trace()
    return (a0,a1,J)
```

When I call

```
(a0,a1,J) = linear_regression(x,y,1,1, 0.1,25)
```

after finishing the for loop, all a0, a1, and J becomes unreasonably high (some numbers like 1e24
for the cost function).

Comment: Have you tried chosing smaller learning rates?

Comment: If I try choosing a smaller learning rate (sth like 0.0001 over 10000 iteration) the results becomes more reasonable (sth like 6 and 2 for the intercept and slope) but given that the input data is very linear it still surprises me why I cannot get a better result. As a cross-check, If I use LinearRegression() in the scikit-Learn package I get a very exact numbers for the coefficients.

Comment: Update: I think I have found the main cause of the issue. If I reshape the input y array to y = y.reshape(-1,1), this will give much more reasonable results.